# How to ssh into a server outside my school server

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-access

I have a computer at my college that I always ssh into from my laptop. However, I'm leaving for break soon, and I realize that whenever I try to ssh in from a different network, the server won't let me in. I really would like to be able to ssh into this computer during break, so what should I do?

Whenever I type this into terminal:

```
XXXXXXXXXX$ ssh -X XXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX
```

The process either won't go forward, or I get this error message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: You can probably login just from your school's network. Most schools doesn't want someone from outside to login to their networkd...
You can ask your computing admin if there's anyway to get in...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, thru ssh-tunnelling. See [this link](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling).

The problem is that, you need to have a box of public fixed IP address outside of your school.

If you have a public floating address, it's still possible.  First, you will need DDNS (just search 'DDNS' on the web), or other method for your server to get your client's IP address.  For example, in your personal web page, somewhere, stores your current client's IP floating IP address.  Then, you need a script/program to fetch that address.  After that, apply the same ssh-tunneling technique.  (Yet, you need a script/program to automatically apply all these steps, yet fail safe issue: When your client's is disconnected, your ssh-tunnel will break, and your ssh-tunneling process died.  Your script need to sense it and re-launch (after getting the new floating IP address).

Oh, the pre-assumption is that, you need to be able to ssh from your school server (your linux box in school) to an outside server (a linux box in your home, for example).  I think most school won't block ssh access to servers outside of the school.